# why is "docker run" used to connect to redis?

Tags: docker, networking, databases, configuration, redis

Trying to understand what's happening here:

```
root@mordor:~# 
root@mordor:~# docker ps -a
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE               COMMAND             CREATED             STATUS              PORTS               NAMES
root@mordor:~# 
root@mordor:~# docker network ls
NETWORK ID          NAME                DRIVER              SCOPE
10d38d6f1fa1        bridge              bridge              local
5b5fde2dd7cc        foo                 bridge              local
1a7946d0b10c        host                host                local
0cbbb6d4f486        none                null                local
root@mordor:~# 
root@mordor:~# docker run --name rd --network foo -d redis redis-server --appendonly yes
ea782770bcff816a642bc700abd2fadd524e3eeca10820e4c158ae4e72eda139
root@mordor:~# 
root@mordor:~# docker container ls
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE               COMMAND                  CREATED             STATUS              PORTS               NAMES
ea782770bcff        redis               "docker-entrypoint.s…"   42 seconds ago      Up 40 seconds       6379/tcp            rd
root@mordor:~# 
root@mordor:~# docker run -it --network foo --rm redis redis-cli -h rd
rd:6379> 
rd:6379> ping
PONG
rd:6379> 
rd:6379> set foo bar
OK
rd:6379> 
rd:6379> get foo
"bar"
rd:6379> 
rd:6379> keys *
1) "foo"
rd:6379>
```

I can see how to spin up the [community](https://hub.docker.com/_/redis) version of `redis`, I only added the `foo` network.  But why is the connection with `run` rather than `exec`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In short, `docker exec` is used to operate an already-running container, while `docker run -it` starts a new container interactively.

When you ran `docker run -it --network foo --rm redis redis-cli -h rd` you created a 2nd container, this time using the `redis-cli` image, which was used to query your running `redis` container.

Were you to repeat the steps you took, and then open another terminal and run `docker container ls`, you would see two running containers.

Reference: https://spin.atomicobject.com/2018/10/04/docker-command-line/

Comment: `docker ps` (or `docker ps -a` if it's terminated) would also show this information.